# QT Query SQL Lite Database

Tags: c++, qt, sqlite

In our sql lite terminal when we type

```
SELECT * FROM Measures
```

we get everything from measure in the database called `OMBI.db`.

But now we want to connect the database via QT C++ GUI development platform. To do this we used the following code:

```
db = QSqlDatabase::addDatabase("QSQLITE");
db.setDatabaseName("/Desktop/project/src/OMBI.db");
bool db_ok = db.open();

qDebug() << db_ok;

QSqlQuery query;
//query.exec("SELECT * FROM Measures");
if(query.exec("SELECT * FROM Measures")){
    while(query.next()){
        qDebug() << query.value(0).toInt();
    }
    qDebug() << query.lastError().text();
    qDebug() << "Inside First if Statement";
}
else
{
    qDebug() << query.lastError().text();
}
```

Note that all our core code for the GUI project is placed under `desktop/project/src` and we've also placed `OMBI.db` database file inside there.

From other questions we were led to believe that if we have successfully opened the database, the line `qDebug() << db_ok;` would return true. Thinking that its been returning true, we thought our problem would be within the `if` statement where we query. But what we've found is that no matter what we set `db.setDatabaseName("");`, it will return true. What might our problem be? I am sure that we are not reading the database in correctly since if we type `db.setDatabaseName("non_existent_random_file");` we still get true.

EDIT:

Also we keep getting the following error when we query:

```
"no such table: Measures Unable to execute statement"
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It will create the database if it doesn't exist.  Probably your path is wrong.  Shouldn't you have  db.setDabaseName("/home/userName/Desktop/.....)?

Comment: from what i understand, whats goes in the bracket of `db.setDabaseName("")` is the path for where the sql lite database is located, but then the thing is when do put the path in, and run our code we get error:  `"no such table: Measures Unable to execute statement" `

Comment: yeah, like I said...your path is wrong.  Either use the absolute path as I described or use a relative path from your Qt project directory.